# Proguard Obfuscate java code to single line & identifiers with _(numbers)

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I've used proguard to obfuscate my jar file. is there any way to remove newline in java code and specify identifiers to have _(numbers) instead of chars using proguard?.

Regards,

Rajan.M

Comment: Proguard obfuscates byte code. As there is no new line inside your byte code, I can't understand your question on that matter. 

Also, can you explain why you want to have such control over obfuscation of variable names in proguard ?

Comment: What is the purpose (of obfuscating your code at all)? Is your code so brilliant and/or proprietary that you have to hide it? If it is proprietary (contains trade secrets) than keep it on network/web accessible server and expose webservices **ONLY**. If (you think that) it is so brilliant let others learn from it.   Or if it is so rubbish let others correct it.

Comment: @sincolas then how come decompilers displays java code in multilines?. and i prefer numbers than chars to obfuscate inorder to make it bit more hard to read.

Comment: @German Arlington its proprietary code i'm working with embeded within desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard only reads and writes Java bytecode, not source code. By default, it picks obfuscated names a, b, c, etc., but you can specify your own set with the option -obfuscationdictionary.

Comment: I created java file with class and functions aligned in single line and compiled to get class file then used proguard for obfuscation but the output we got is properly aligned classes and functions??